Influxdb Command prompt login issue
Influx dB cmd receiving status code as 401 from server.
We have tried to use auth command. But there we are unable to enter the password.
We need to login to influx through cmd. We need to integrate LoadRunner with Grafana using influx db.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.5936]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

   C:\Users\****\Downloads\influxdb2-2.7.6-windows>influx --username 
   **** --password ****
   Connected to http://localhost:8086 version v2.7.6
   InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.5
   > SHOW DATABASES
   ERR: received status code 401 from server
   >


Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.5936]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

   C:\Users\****\Downloads\influxdb2-2.7.6-windows>influx
   Connected to http://localhost:8086 version v2.7.6
   InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.5
   > auth
   username: admin
   password:
   > show databasese
   ERR: received status code 401 from server
   >

Here (2) we are unable to enter the password.

Not sure if this is even on-topic here. But your question would benefit from information of what exactly you have done and how the error presents itself exactly (preferably both in text, not screenshots).

(1) doesn't seem to succeed either. If the problem is that password contains special characters and the question is how they could be reliably passed in the command line, that may rather belong to https://superuser.com

This question is similar to: InfluxDB CLI 401 Unauthorized. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
